# AWS EMR Apache Spark and custom S3 endpoint in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I use Apache Spark and Redshift in VPС and also use AWS S3 for source data and temp  data for Redshift COPY.

Right now I suspect that performance of read/write from/to AWS S3 is not good enough and based on the suggestion in the following discussion https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/318 I have created S3 endpoint within the VPC. Right now I can't see any performance difference before and after S3 endpoint creation when I'm loading data from S3.

In Apache Spark I read data in the following way:

```
spark.read.csv("s3://example-dev-data/dictionary/file.csv")
```

Do I need to add/configure some extra logic/configuration on AWS EMR Apache Spark in order to proper use of AWS S3 endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

The S3 VPC Endpoint is a [Gateway Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) so you have to put a new entry in the routing table of your subnets where you start EMR clusters that route the traffic to the endpoint.